# show MAX column for group by - show all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregation

I have a DB in mysql, and I need to create a MAX(date) column according to "GROUP BY", but I want to see all rows.
The PK's are group, Start Date. I want to find the max(StartDate) for each group - but still see all records, for example:

```
group   |  StartDate  |  MAX(StartDate)
  1     |  2015-10-01 |   2015-10-20
  1     |  2015-10-10 |   2015-10-20
  1     |  2015-10-20 |   2015-10-20
  2     |  2015-09-24 |   2015-10-05
  2     |  2015-10-05 |   2015-10-05
```

how can I do so? using "group by" on group leaves me with only 2 rows...
thank you!

EDIT: I know I can do so by joining the table with itself and calculate MAX(StartDate) in the joined table, but the code for the table is really long - I want to know if there a more elegant way to do so...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with variables, without joining the table twice:

```
  select t.*,
         (@d := if(@g = `group`, @d,
                   if(@g := `group`, startdate, startdate)
                  )
         ) as maxdate
  from table t cross join
       (select @g := '', @d := '') params
  order by `group`, startdate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*, t2.m_date
from your_table t1
join
(
  select  `group`, max(startdate) as m_date
  from your_table
  group by `group`
) t2 on t1.`group` = t2.`group`
```

Comment: I thought about that - but the code for basic table id really long, contains many joins and it'll just be a massive code... I want to now if theres another way, so the code will look a bit more "elegant"